# back to top link hide under text

Tags: javascript, css

I am displaying back to top link in my mvc project.
Layout:

```
<a id="back-to-top" href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg back-to-top" role="button" title="Click to return on the top page" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span></a>
```

Css:

```
.back-to-top {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    display:none;
}
```

JS:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
                if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
                    $('#back-to-top').fadeIn();
                } else {
                    $('#back-to-top').fadeOut();
                }
            });
            // scroll body to 0px on click
            $('#back-to-top').click(function () {
                $('#back-to-top').tooltip('hide');
                $('body,html').animate({
                    scrollTop: 0
                }, 800);
                return false;
            });

            $('#back-to-top').tooltip('show');
```

This button/link, is working correctly. but on some pages, it is hide under the body content /table. on some pages it is showing correctly (infront of text).
I want to display this link in front of text on all the pages.
Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Simply set `z-index` for that element:

```
.back-to-top {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    display: none;

    z-index: 9999;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. 
I just added z-index:99999; to css.
It is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Use with `z-index`

```
.back-to-top {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    display:none;

    z-index: 9999999;
}
```